# Basic probability question mutual exclusivity random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

The following problem is given:

The true value, resp. measured value of the spin of an electron is de-noted by $X$, resp. $Y$. A possible measurement error is denoted by the random variable $Z$. The random variables $X$, $Y$, $Z$ take the values $1,-1$ and we have $Y=XZ$,
$P(X= 1) = 1 - P(X=-1) =1/3;P(Z= 1) = 1 - P(Z=-1) = 9/10$.

Moreover $X$ and $Z$ are independent.

Now we have to calculate $P(Y=1)$.

I got $P(Y=1)=P(XZ=1)=P(X=1,Z=1 \cup X=-1,Z=-1)=P(X=1,Z=1)+P(X=-1,Z=-1)$
My question: How do we that we can make the last step?

Comment: Use $P(X=1,Z=1)=P(X=1)P(Z=1)$ using independence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event $Y=1$ happens when either $X=Z=1$ or $X=Z=-1$. 
$$P(X=Z=1)=\frac{1}{3}\frac{9}{10}=\frac{9}{30}$$
and
$$P(X=Z=-1)=\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{10}=\frac{2}{30}$$
Therefore $P(Y=1)= \frac{11}{30}$.